# Android - GUI not found

Tags: android, eclipse, user-interface

I'm working on my first Android App using the Android SDK for Eclipse and  the eclipse plugin (ADT) 
Recently I've encountered an error while trying to build an UI in XML with the GUI. Any time I try to open a layout XML file, I can't find the graphical interface (No Layout TAB, just the source and the design tabs).

I have to write all the XML code. I think that graphical editor is broken and I don't know what I have to do. Anyone else have the same problem or any suggestions?

Comment: I've never encountered or heard of your problem I'm afraid, but I can tell you this:  Writing all the xml code by hand has its advantages in the long run.

Comment: Yeah, but it didn't resolve my problem !

Comment: I think you should not give up and start using DroidDraw (not saying its bad though). Just reinstall ADT or even try downloading eclipse again and extracting it to a different folder and then installing ADT in a fresh Eclipse may help you find out something!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try to re install the ADT Plugin ?? 
if it doesn't work , you can use this website , it is very useful , and then just copy/paste your code :

refer this [link](http://www.droiddraw.org/)

Regards

Answer (score 0):

May be you have already try it, but try to remove then reinstall eclipse android plugin. For me it worked when I had a similar issue. If not work, witch version of Eclipse do you have (Not only the number version, but also give if you dowload eclipse for java developer, ...) and witch Android SDK do you use ?
JHelp

Comment: Version of SDK : android-sdk_r11-windows , the latest one I guess, I download it in this website : http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Comment: And the Eclipse version : eclipse-jee-helios-SR2-win32-x86_64, for jee developer